# Oozie coordinator issue

Tags: hadoop, workflow, cloudera, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have oozie installation as part of the cloudera installation.
I'm trying to execute the coordinator workflow fro the example with the following configuration in the coordinator.xml.

```
<coordinator-app name="cron-coord" frequency="${coord:minutes(60)}" start="${start}" end="${end}" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2">
```

With this configuration i expected the workflow to be executed every 1 hour , but it seems that the workflow has been executed every 5  minutes  , does anyone have answer for this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm the version of the coord xml in HDFS matches this, and your `oozie.coord.application.path` configuration property points to this file (i.e. have you changed this file on local disk, but not uploaded to HDFS? If you have, did you kill off any old coords instances and re-run for the new xml def?)

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the start time prior to the current time? If so, Oozie will work in the catch up mode until all delayed actions have been scheduled. The "frequency" setting does not apply to the catch-up mode.

Answer (score 0):

You may give time coords in *hours* instead of *minutes* as :

```
coordinator-app name="cron-coord" frequency="${coord:hours(1)}" start="${start}" end="${end}" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2"
```